# Is it possible to configure Computer A as a network gateway for Computer B? (for Wireshark monitoring)

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, gateway

**First of all, to avoid the X/Y problem, here's what I'm trying to achieve:** I want to monitor Computer B's raw network traffic from Computer A using Wireshark (more specifically `npcap`).

This is possible if the "Remote" machine is a actually local VM, because VMware will create virtual network adapters for the virtual machines, and those can be easily sniffed from Wireshark, just like the real interfaces.

I was hoping that a similar custom "Virtual Gateway" could be created, or one of VMware's existing ones could be reused, so that the second computer could connect to it, and I could analyze the network traffic with Wireshark. So my question is, is there a software that can create a virtual network gateway that other computers can connect to, to allow remote packet sniffing with npcap (Wireshark), or can I use one of VMware's existing adapters to achieve this.

Both computers run Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention an OS, just a "computer", but you did mention libpcap rather than Npcap or WinPcap, so I'm going to assume it runs or is able to run Linux or BSD.

Linux *itself* will act as a gateway without any additional software, and is indeed used for building real routers/gateways in many networks. If you already have two network interfaces on different subnets, all you need is to enable IP forwarding in the kernel using `sysctl`:

```
sysctl net.{ipv4,ipv6}.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Hosts on one interface can now use you as a gateway to reach other interfaces, or whatever else you have in your routing table.

(If you want NAT, that's done through nftables or iptables – it's not part of IP forwarding. Make sure *tables doesn't have rules to drop all forwarded traffic.)

Though you don't need an L3 *gateway* here – it would likely be simpler to use the host as a L2 bridge (with both network interfaces then belonging to the same subnet), and monitor packets going through the bridge in 'promisc' mode while requiring no changes to the other host's configuration:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge; ip link set br0 up
ip link set eth0 master br0; ip link set eth1 master br0
```

Most BSDs similarly have full support for IP forwarding and L2 bridging in the kernel, though the commands are of course very different.

Windows *used to have* support for IP routing; in "consumer" versions it was found as the non-configurable "Internet Connection Sharing" feature. I don't know if it still exists in Windows 10/11. There are probably other threads explaining how to enable it.

Windows *does* have built-in support for Ethernet bridging – you can still create a bridge through `ncpa.cpl` by selecting two or more Ethernet (not Wi-Fi) interfaces.

Comment: I added a tag specifying Windows. Also, I was unaware that there are different types of the pcap library. So in my case, it would be npcap. I'll edit my question